# what is best way to rotate an image using php or convert command?

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-rotation

what is best way to rotate an image using php or convert command?

Comment: Hi there. We rather prefer questions that have been researched here, so I am downvoting. How to rotate an image using `convert` is in the IM manual.

Answer (score 2):

With Imagick, use [rotateImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.rotateimage.php)

```php
<?php
$image = new Imagick("source.kpg");
$image->rotateImage ( 'white', 90.0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). The following command will rotate the image:

```
convert original_file.jpg -rotate 90 new_file.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP function `imagerotate`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Example:

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
?>
```